# Recieving unknown access violation when using arrays and files

Tags: c++, arrays, file-io, compiler-errors

I've just started learning how to program a few months ago and this is my first programming language. I've written up this program to pull a customer number from "BeginningBalance.dat" along with customer purchases and payments.

After reading in the charges for each customer it will add a finance charge and total everything, then it will write the new ending balances for each customer number in the opposite order.

So beginningdata.dat looks like

```
111
200.00
300.00
50.00
222
300.00
200.00
100.00
```

and NewBalance.dat should look like

```
222
402.00
111 
251.00
```

Now all that is being read into NewBalance.dat is
    -858993460-9.25596e+061333655222402111251-858993460

Heres my code if anyone can help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int count = 0;
    const int size = 100;
    double customer_beg_balance, customer_purchases, customer_payments, finance_charge_cost, finance_charge = .01;
    int customer_number[size];
    double new_balance[size];
    double total_beg_balances=0,total_finance_charges=0,total_purchases=0,total_payments=0,total_end_balances=0;

    ifstream beginning_balance;
    beginning_balance.open("beginningbalance.dat");

    while(beginning_balance>>customer_number[count])
    {
        beginning_balance >> customer_beg_balance;
        beginning_balance >> customer_purchases;
        beginning_balance >> customer_payments;

        finance_charge_cost = customer_beg_balance * finance_charge;

        new_balance[count] = customer_beg_balance + finance_charge_cost + customer_purchases - customer_payments;
        total_beg_balances+=customer_beg_balance;
        total_finance_charges+=finance_charge_cost;
        total_purchases+=customer_purchases;
        total_payments+=customer_payments;
        total_end_balances+=new_balance[count];

        cout<<fixed<<setprecision(2)<<setw(8)
            <<"Cust No  "<<"Beg. Bal.  "<<"Finance Charge  "<<"Purchases  "<<"Payments  "<<"Ending Bal.\n"
            <<customer_number[count]<<"        "
            <<customer_beg_balance<<"        "
            <<finance_charge_cost<<"       "
            <<customer_purchases<<"     "
            <<customer_payments<<"         "
            <<new_balance[count]<<endl;


        count++;
    }

    cout<<"\nTotals     "
        <<total_beg_balances<<"        "
        <<total_finance_charges<<"       "
        <<total_purchases<<"     "
        <<total_payments<<"         "
        <<total_end_balances<<endl;

    ofstream new_balance_file;
    new_balance_file.open("NewBalance.dat");

    while(new_balance_file << customer_number[count] && count >= 0)
    {
        new_balance_file << new_balance[count];
        count--;
    }

    new_balance_file.close();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while(new_balance_file << customer_number[count])
{
    new_balance_file << new_balance[count];
    count--;
}
```

Is not right.  You'll run over the beginning of the array and start negative accesses since you don't limit count.

Comment: What can I do to limit count from running into negatives?

Comment: Something like: while(new_balance_file << customer_number[count], count >= 0), or simpler yet just do if (whatever) break; to get out of the loop.

Comment: This worked now I'm having trouble with the correct values being read in :/

Comment: I'd close the question since you got past that particular problem, play with it a little yourself, and if you can't work it out toss another one up stating how far you got.  Chances are you'll work it out now that you're past the file access error (you thought you had).  I'll check back later and take another look if its still up though. :) Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

In general, an access violation during a memory read means that either you've made a pointer math mistake (not likely in this case since you don't do any pointer math) or you've read significantly past the end or before the beginning of an array.

Answer (score 0):

Learn to compile with all warnings enabled and debugging information. For GCC, that means `g++ -Wall -g`. Then learn how to use a debugger (like `gdb` for Linux) and run a program step by step.

Comment: not helpful. Ironically, with -Wall the only message is `warning: ignoring return value of ‘int system(const char*)’`...